# Uwsgi and flask with unix socket instead of URL

Tags: linux, debian, python, socket, flask

I was trying to find out the difference between a socket as a unix file and a socket that is a ip and port.

If I switch something like uwsgi to use a file instead of a port and ip, how do I then access uwsgi as a URL in my browser, since no port is now specified for my flask application.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the first result on Google for how to bind a flask UWSGI app to a unix socket, here is the answer to the question in the title.

From flask:

```py
app.run(host="unix:///tmp/app.sock")
```

or

```bash
FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host=unix:///tmp/app.sock
```

If using gunicorn:

```bash
gunicorn -w 4 package:app --bind unix:/tmp/app.sock
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run uwsgi to listen to a TCP/IP port, for example `uwsgi --http :80` , if you change it to listen to a Unix socket (for ex: `uwsgi --socket :8000` ) then as you said, this is local only, no web service (TCP/IP) is exposed to the Internet and you have to put a web server like nginx in front of uwsgi as 'proxy' that can get the http requests from the outside world (see https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281 for a django example instead of Flask)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of using a Unix socket.

Comment: @larsks It does answer the question. It specifies exactly what you need (nginx or similar) in the middle to access it from a browser.

Comment: It does not provide any example of using a unix socket. The examples in this answer show how to use network sockets. A unix socket is an entry in the filesystem, not a network port.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't support making requests to Unix sockets. [Here's a feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451721) that was opened with Chromium, but they responded that they would not be adding support for that use case.